# How to reference a different field from within source criteria of a List/ComboBox in LO Base

Tags: forms, libreoffice-base

I've started working with LibreOffice Base, coming from MS Access and I want to reference a ListBox (lstNameA) selected value from a second ListBox (lstNameB) in order to filter the second ListBoxes records.
I've searched but can't find anything.

Comment: For filtering one list by another, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47836362/5100564, including Ratslinger's answer under "Edit 2".

Comment: My own transition from Access to LO took quite a bit of doing.  I had worked w/ Access for many years.  Putting my Access into LO was like putting a big foot into a smaller shoe.  I had to learn much about Star Basic, and also change the way I was doing a number of things in a number of places.  But little by little I have moved over 100 databases now to LO and I'm very happy to be done w/ Windows (except for a few things that won't yet run on Linux).  Keep an open mind about what is realistic in LO and it's easier I think.  You won't be able to do everything the same in LO.  Cheers.